# Page Object pattern alternative for statically typed languages (e.g.: Java, C#)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, pageobjects

I have to build test automation for a web project. I will use Java language and Selenium WebDriver. Before I usually used the Page Object pattern and didn't see anyone else using a different pattern. But now I want to understand what other patterns are there for web testing automation for statically typed languages (e.g.: Java, C#). Have you used other patterns? Why are they better?

I tried to create an alternative to the Page Object pattern and created a Step Objects pattern. This pattern allows you to store actions in Java objects You can see the use case - [Xteps Step Object pattern example](https://github.com/evpl/xteps#Step-objects). But I haven't applied this pattern at work yet and I'm not sure if it's better than Page Object.

Comment: Page Object Model as it's implemented now is a bit out-dated and needs some modifications to work with dynamic sites.  I like your approach better since we're dealing with a timeline... you want to be able to re-use and/or re-order specifc actions or groups of actions.  I take a similar approach with a custom action class and a procedure class.  So a procedure is a collection of actions and a test is a collection of procedures.  Each action can pass/fail, and each procedure passes if all actions within it pass, else it fails.  It makes re-ordering and outputting of reports a simpler task.

Comment: I find it more useful to have re-usable actions and procedures... not really re-usable page-objects... the metaphor was always a bit off there but made more sense when webdriverwaits were not necessary.  POM did do a nice job of making a re-usable collection of webelement selectors for any given view of the site....

Comment: You could also build the page object model into the steps approach.  (If you find that changes to the site require you to update webelement selectors in multiple places throughout the code...)

Comment: @pcalkins Thank you. I sort of understood your approach, but maybe you posted an example of your code somewhere? I would like to see an example.

Comment: Sure you can see the code here (gui and file-based app):  https://github.com/petecalkins/Browsermator-Selenium4

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks, I'll take a look at your code. And I would like to note that almost all of us use the OOP paradigm in tests, but tests are still written in an imperative style because it is just a sequence of actions and there can be no other way.

Comment: Exactly!  We're working with a timeline.  One thing follows another.